# How Adobe Flex works on Android / iOS

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex

I was just evaluating Adobe Flex for a project. But came across this question.

Like PhoneGap/HTML5 apps run on top of Browser/WebKit of the operating system, How does Flex works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Flex targets Adobe Integrated Runtime (AIR) or Flash player as runtime for the application. More on [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Flex#Overview).

For iOS, the runtime is bundled with every application created for iOS, at the time of packaging. For Android, you can bundle runtime for every app or separately download and install the AIR app from Play store on your phone. (Refer: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/848409)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Amar.. My app has lot of db transactions and web service calls.. and data to show in list views.. ( infinite.. like news feed ) .. Camera API integration, etc.. how do you feel? to go with flex or native? Esp on the DB part.. how much data I can store? The DB is run under Air Runtime right? should be limitted ?

Comment: @SyamS I have worked only on native iOS apps and not AIR, so can't advice you on this one, sry! You can search through questions on SO or on Adobe forum to get some help deciding this.